# How to create shortcuts in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I often use `cd ..` command in terminal. I want to replace the command with `..` or some other shortcut.

Can I do that? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually called alias and not shortcut.

to do that:

```
alias CD='cd ..'
```

Now you can use the command CD instead of `cd ..`

But you have to note this will be just dynamic and you'll l ose all aliases when you close terminal and start again. To make it permanent you have to add it to your `.bashrc`.

Run the command

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Add the above line (alias declaration) then save and close and source the `.bashrc` using

```
source .bashrc
```

And now the alias CD is permanent .

---

You can list all aliases you use in your system(ubuntu come with some default aliases such as ls, egrep...), you can just type the command `alias` and you can list all aliases in the system

Comment: Worked like charm!! BTW, what does `source .bashrc` line does?

Comment: It just "fetch" i.e run the file,     Execute commands from a file in the current shell.