# Missing man page of Clang

Tags: manpage, clang

I installed `Clang 3.6` following the instructions [here](http://llvm.org/apt/) (the latest version in Ubuntu repository is 3.5):

```
# to retrieve the archive signature
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -

# to install all packages
apt-get install clang-3.6 clang-3.6-doc libclang-common-3.6-dev libclang-3.6-dev libclang1-3.6 libclang1-3.6-dbg libllvm-3.6-ocaml-dev libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6-dbg lldb-3.6 llvm-3.6 llvm-3.6-dev llvm-3.6-doc llvm-3.6-examples llvm-3.6-runtime clang-modernize-3.6 clang-format-3.6 python-clang-3.6 lldb-3.6-dev
```

However, after the installation, `man clang` says

```
No manual entry for clang
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

but `man clang-3.6` works. Also, neither `man clang++` or `man clang++-3.6` works. How do I make `man clang` and `man clang++` work and open the man page as it is already in the system? I also want to use the commands `clang` and `clang++` instead of `clang-3.6` and `clang++-3.6`.

Comment: Did you try `man --update clang` to force an update of the man database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create some symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s "$(command -v clang-3.6)" /usr/local/bin/clang
sudo ln -s "$(command -v clang++-3.6)" /usr/local/bin/clang++
sudo ln -s "$(man -w clang-3.6)" /usr/share/man/man1/clang.1.gz
```

The first two are for the `clang` and `clang++` commands, and the third for the manpage. If the manpages for `clang` and `clang++` are supposed to be the same, you can repeat it with`clang++.1.gz` instead of `clang.1.gz`.

And while you're at it, file a feature request with [the package maintainers](http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Packaging).

Comment: what does the command `command` do? There's no man page for it.

Comment: @ajay it's a builtin, so check `man bash`. Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250/70524.

Comment: I checked in `/usr/share/man/man1`, there is no `clang.1.gz` file but there is `clang-3.6.1.gz` file. Shall I replace the `clang.1.gz`  with `clang-3.6.1.gz` in your answer?

Comment: @ajay No. What would be the point of that? We are creating a `clang.1.gz` link because it doesn't exist it in the first place. If it already existed, you wouldn't have problems with `man clang`.

Comment: I just realized that. Sorry for posting a stupid comment. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

#### In short answer

run the commands:

```
sudo ln -s `which clang-3.6` /usr/local/bin/clang
sudo ln -s `which clang++-3.6` /usr/local/bin/clang++
```

---

#### Details

You should use symlink for that.

```
which command
```

Will show the place of the binary then you can make the symlink. for example i'll make a symlink as example for command `mkdir`.

```
$ which mkdir
/bin/mkdir
```

Now i'm going to make symlink for command mkdir:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/mkdir /bin/makedir
```

then for now you can use `makedir` instead of `mkdir`.

**Another approach**

- `alias`

  Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/646384/150504) for more info.
- `ln`

  Same (symlinks) can be done for man pages. Or you can [create your own man page](https://askubuntu.com/a/646392/150504).

Comment: @Downvoter. Why?!!!

Comment: +1, you seem to have a troll following you around. My sympathies.

Comment: @muru, thanks, it become fishy, I really start to be uncomfortable here. Thanks  for your support

Comment: +1. It's really annoying when people downvote without leaving a comment.

Comment: @ajay thanks even I didn't see your up yet hhhh

Comment: +1 I also don’t understand the downvote

Comment: @Maythux Are my formatting correct? If not simply rollback :)